# Question about NodeJS regarding Global Variables and Discord.js v13.6.0

Tags: node.js, discord.js

```js
if (interaction.customId == 'forwardButton') {
    console.log(pageNum);
    pageNum++;
}
```

Hi, I'm having a problem with programming a command for my Discord.js Bot. I have trouble with trying to create and increment global variables that can be accessed across files. So far I have 2 files, one file has the variable `let pageNum = 0;` and is being exported via module.exports into the second file which contains the code above ^^. It seems when I run the command and click the forward button, pageNum will log 0 and if I click it again, it'll log 1, but if I run the command again and click the forward button, pageNum will log 2 instead of 0, does anyone know why?

I'm trying to get it so that when the command is run a second time, pageNum is reset back to 0

Answer (score 0):

It's because when you click you add `1` to variable so when it was `0` after click it will be `1`. However when you don't renew variable to the normal state that is `pageNum = 0` you will increment value in variable over and over again.
So what you need to do is when you start script another time recover numPage to state of `0`